# geeting HTTP Post BAD request converting CURL code to C# HTTP POST

Tags: c#, curl

Can someone please assist need to do post to url working fine on curl but not throufh C#  HTTPPOST..

Here Curl code :
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZWRpdG9yOnhYTXEgM09QNyB4WjlkIHpET3IgOVNhTiB1S3lx=="-H "description: {"path":"/shows/sheriffs-el-dorado-county/2020-2021-season/formats/","title":"HD-SEIN860","date":"2021-02-08","description":"STRIP / HD-SEIN860 / Airdate 02-10-2021"}" -X POST --data-binary @"C:/Users/sahithi.illindala/Downloads/HD-OZMR13091.pdf" http://ersyndication.wpengine.com/library/wp-json/wp/v2/media

Here is C# HTTPClient pOSt

using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://ersyndication.wpengine.com/library/wp-json/wp/v2/media"))

```
        {

            req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic ZWRpdG9yOnhYTXEgM09QNyB4WjlkIHpET3IgOVNhTiB1S3lx==");

            //hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("attachment; filename = HD - SEIN860.pdf"));

            req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=HD-SEIN860.pdf");

            req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("description", "{\"path\":\"/shows/sheriffs-el-dorado-county/2020-2021-season/formats/\",\"title\":\"HD-SEIN860\",\"date\":\"2021-02-08\",\"description\":\"SI1234 / HD-SEIN860 / Airdate 02-10-2021\"}");

            req.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText("path"));

                  req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);


            var JsonResults = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Curl but it looks like you want to use `StreamContent` instead of `StringContent`. And fyi, you wouldn't use `StringContent` to post form url encoded data, you would use `FormUrlEncodedContent`

Comment: thanks for your response. do you have any example that use stream content ... how to apply in my code

Comment: and one more there is no body only headers in request